# Why is casting Derived** to Base*const* forbidden?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486056/casting-array-of-pointers-to-objects), i saw the answer by Naveen containing a link to [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/proper-inheritance.html#faq-21.2) page, which basically says, that casting from Derived** to Base** is forbidden since could change a pointer to an pointer to a Derived1 object point to a pointer to a Derived2 object (like: `*derived1PtrPtr=derived2Ptr`).

OK, i understand this is evil ...

But when casting `Derived**` to `Base*const*` this is not even possible, so whats the reason that this is not allowed anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that, if you really need to, you can cast any pointer type to any other pointer type. For instance, you can cast to `void*` as an intermediate step.

Second, with pointers-to-pointers, it's not so much that there's a reason to make particular cases hard as that there are no special rules to make any particular cases easy.

Basically, you have a pointer to `X` - where `X` in your case happens to be another pointer. Some `X` cases get special treatment (e.g. derived classes can implicitly cast to bases) - but your `X` is not one of them. It's not the base class - it's a pointer. There are no implicit casts defined for `derived**`, other than to `void*` - you can't even implicitly cast `derived**` to `void**`.

I don't think the `const` has much to do with it in this case, though I could be missing something.

Comment: hmm so the designers of C++ let us be totally on our own there (i.e. no real help by the compiler). hmm thats quite disappointing...

Comment: It's the designers of C really - C++ is just copying the same overall approach for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to cast `Derived**` to `Base**` in the case of multiple inheritance. The base might live anywhere within the object, meaning the value inside the first pointer would need to be changed. And in your case, that pointer is even (becoming) `const`. So you need to introduce a new variable and assign.

In the likely case of single inheritance, I suppose `reinterpret_cast` would have defined behavior due to memory layout guarantees. Definitely something to think twice about though.